# expressvpn on disconnect does not restore previous resolv.conf

Tags: dns, vpn, openvpn

When I disconnect from expressvpn, the resolv.conf file contains expressvpn references that were not there when I connected.

Specifically it sets a `nameserver` to a non-existent IP address and adds `expressvpn` to the `search` domain.

What is the best way to have the `expressvpn disconnect` restore my previous resolv.conf. I could wrap the disconnect in a script that restores from a backup, but that requires root -- and there may be a standard way. I don't see anything on the expressvpn site.

Comment: Sounds like an ExpressVPN bug.  The closest thing I can think of is a script that restores `resolv.conf` back to what it should be.  However, this can break things in some cases.  What OS version are you using, maybe I can write a script that does this stuff for you.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'll report it to ExpressVPN and see what comes of it. I'm running Ubuntu 19.04. Like to see your script.

Comment: I'll have to write it still, but it'll be Python based because Python is fun and is capable of running things.  Give me some time though, it takes time to make complex scripts xD

Comment: @ThomasWard I like Python too so I'm looking forward to seeing what you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressVPN responded that they consider this a feature. So I have done this:

```
 sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
 sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

I then hardcode /etc/resolv.conf as at least:

```
 nameserver 1.1.1.1
 nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

On ExpressVPN connect, this file is replaced with the VPN DNS IPs and on disconnect this resolv.conf is restored.

This has been working through 19.04 to 19.10 without fewer problems than I used to have when `systemd-resolved` was managing the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, it looks like a bug in `expressvpn`. I've used this workaround to make it work: I have made a backup of my `resolv.conf` file once, using:

```
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak
```

And after that when I want to disconnect, I don't run the usual command:

```
expressvpn disconnect
```

Instead I run:

```
expressvpn disconnect && sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf.bak /etc/resolv.conf
```

I don't type it in full, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to find it quickly in my bash history. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Exactly the same problem, where ExpressVPN was modifying resolv.conf, but not replacing it when I disconnected from VPN.  Now it's working flawlessly.

> sudo apt-get install resolvconf
>
> sudo vi /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base

Add your name servers to base and save, for example:

> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>
> nameserver 8.8.4.4

Copy base to resolv.conf

> cp /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base /etc/resolv.conf

[ExpressVPN Support:  Set DNS Servers for Linux](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/troubleshooting/set-dns-servers-for-linux/)